# JTable sorter not working

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have a very simple JTable that I want to sort in ascending order by column 0. The code is very simple. But it is not able to sort the rows properly. I can not figure out what is wrong. Following is my code:

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TableSorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableSorter();
    }

    public TableSorter() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              try {


       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | 
       IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


            DefaultTableModel model =  new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"X", "Y", }, 0);

            model.addRow(new Object[]{5, 8});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{10, 5});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{50, 60});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{100, 60});

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel());
            table.setRowSorter(sorter);


            List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
            sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
            sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

   }
```

[Here is the result when I run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYdM9.png)

Results:

```
X    y
10   5
100  60
5    8
50   60
```

Any help will be appreciated. The result is attached. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That image would better have been pasted as text. The row sorter is sorting the numbers as if they were strings. Declare the columns as type `Integer` & it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) :

> Warning: DefaultTableModel returns a column class of Object. When
>   DefaultTableModel is used with a TableRowSorter this will result in
>   extensive use of toString, which for non-String data types is
>   expensive. If you use DefaultTableModel with a TableRowSorter you are
>   strongly encouraged to override getColumnClass to return the
>   appropriate type.

You need to override getColumnClass of your table model like :

```
DefaultTableModel model =  new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"X", "Y", }, 0)
{
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) 
        {
              Class<?> returnValue;
              if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) 
              {
                  returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
              } 
              else 
              {
                 returnValue = Object.class;
              }

              return returnValue;

       };
    };
```

In your case it is comparing `Integer.toString()` on integers and hence the wrong order that you see.
By overriding `getColumnClass()` to return `Integer` type, you will get comparison of integers by their values.