# JTable Comparator Double not sorting quite right

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, comparator

So I have a JTable created using Netbeans' GUIBuilder that has many columns holding different kinds of data and the columns can be sorted using comparators. my problem is that with the double columns, when the table gets sorted, the value 10.0 never seems to go into the right spot. when going in ascending order, 10.0 comes after 1.0 but before 2.0. other than that the sorting works with dealing with other double values.

Here is what i am running.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;


public class OData extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public OData() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        OTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle"); // NOI18N
        setTitle(bundle.getString("OsuData.title")); // NOI18N
        setName("Form"); // NOI18N

        jScrollPane1.setName("jScrollPane1"); // NOI18N

        OTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Column1", "Column2", "Column3"
            }
        ));
        OTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        OTable.setName("OTable"); // NOI18N
        OTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(OTable);
        OTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        if (OTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(15);
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue(bundle.getString("OsuData.jTable1.columnModel.title5")); // NOI18N
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(15);
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue(bundle.getString("OsuData.jTable1.columnModel.title6")); // NOI18N
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(15);
            OTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue(bundle.getString("OsuData.jTable1.columnModel.title7")); // NOI18N
        }

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(jScrollPane1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1185, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jScrollPane1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 295, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    private static void LoadTable() 
    { // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Load The Table">
        String LoadLine = null;
        DefaultTableModel dtm =  (DefaultTableModel) OTable.getModel();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
            while ((LoadLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Vector data= new Vector();
                StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(LoadLine,"\t");
                while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    String nextToken = st1.nextToken();
                    data.add(nextToken);
                }
            System.out.println(data);
            dtm.addRow(data);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // </editor-fold>

    public static void SaveTable(JTable table)
    { // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Save The Table">
        try{
            TableModel OTM = OTable.getModel();
            FileWriter OTW = new FileWriter("data.txt");

            for(int i=0; i< OTM.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j < OTM.getColumnCount(); j++)
                {
                OTW.write(OTM.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"\t");
                }
            OTW.write("\n");
            }

        OTW.close();

    }catch(IOException e){ System.out.println(e); }
    } // </editor-fold>


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OData.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new OData().setVisible(true);

                OData.LoadTable();

                OTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

                TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> rowSorterOD = (TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>)OTable.getRowSorter();
                rowSorterOD.setComparator(8, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private static javax.swing.JTable OTable;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

data.txt contains this:

```
4.0 2.0 3.0
7.0 6.0 6.0
9.0 7.0 7.0
3.0 2.0 1.0
5.0 3.0 3.0
7.0 6.0 6.0
8.0 8.0 6.0
3.0 1.0 1.0
9.0 10.0    6.0
2.0 1.0 2.0
3.0 2.0 3.0
5.0 4.0 4.0
8.0 6.0 6.0
9.0 7.0 8.0
```

Sorry if this went a bit long

Comment: You're sorting the values as `String`, I'd do some research into why sorting numbers represented by `String` doesn't give the results you're expecting

Comment: I don't really see what you are trying to lead me to. I can't seem to change the comparator by replaceing the String to Double if you were telling me to change them.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"I can't seem to change the comparator by replaceing the String to Double"* Why not?

Comment: You have only 3 columns, why are you setting comparator for column 8 ?

Comment: @JamesRudolph See the linked answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030032/jtable-sorter-not-working/44031076#44031076 You have to override `getColumnClass` of your `TableModel` to return `Double.class` for the column that contains the `Double` values.

Comment: After trying different thing relating to the linked answers for the past few days. I still cant get anything to work, I just end up having the same problem as when I started. probably going to just have to give up on getting this sorting stuff to work properly with the doubles on my table.